# Robot toy simulator

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, interview-questions, state-machine

I have already flunked the test with this code so don't feel bad for cheating any employer. I didn't get any feedback though just wondering what could have gone wrong.

You don't need to get into the functionality, just the overall design. What are short-coming of this code which disqualifies it from being production quality.

> ## Toy Robot Simulator
>
> ### Description
>
> - The application is a simulation of a toy robot moving on a square tabletop,   of dimensions 5 units x 5 units.
> - There are no other obstructions on the table surface.
> - The robot is free to roam around the surface of the table, but must be   prevented from falling to destruction. Any movement that would
>     result in the   robot falling from the table must be prevented,
>     however further valid   movement commands must still be allowed.
>
> Create an application that can read in commands of the following form:
>
> ```
> PLACE X,Y,F
> MOVE
> LEFT
> RIGHT
> REPORT
> ```
>
> - PLACE will put the toy robot on the table in position X,Y and facing NORTH,   SOUTH, EAST or WEST.
> - The origin (0,0) can be considered to be the SOUTH WEST most corner.
> - The first valid command to the robot is a PLACE command, after that, any   sequence of commands may be issued, in any order, including
>     another PLACE   command. The application should discard all commands
>     in the sequence until   a valid PLACE command has been executed.
> - MOVE will move the toy robot one unit forward in the direction it is   currently facing.
> - LEFT and RIGHT will rotate the robot 90 degrees in the specified direction   without changing the position of the robot.
> - REPORT will announce the X,Y and F of the robot. This can be in any form,   but standard output is sufficient.
> - A robot that is not on the table can choose the ignore the MOVE, LEFT, RIGHT   and REPORT commands.
> - Input can be from a file, or from standard input, as the developer chooses.
> - Provide test data to exercise the application.
>
> ### Constraints
>
> - The toy robot must not fall off the table during movement. This also   includes the initial placement of the toy robot.
> - Any move that would cause the robot to fall must be ignored.
>
> ### Example Input and Output
>
> #### Example a
>
> ```
> PLACE 0,0,NORTH
> MOVE
> REPORT
> ```
>
> Expected output:
>
> ```
> 0,1,NORTH
> ```
>
> #### Example b
>
> ```
> PLACE 0,0,NORTH
> LEFT
> REPORT
> ```
>
> Expected output:
>
> ```
> 0,0,WEST
> ```
>
> #### Example c
>
> ```
> PLACE 1,2,EAST
> MOVE
> MOVE
> LEFT
> MOVE
> REPORT
> ```
>
> Expected output
>
> ```
> 3,3,NORTH
> ```
>
> ### Deliverables
>
> The Ruby source files, the test data and any test code.
>
> It is not required to provide any graphical output showing the
>   movement of the toy robot.

[GitHub](https://github.com/bapusethi/toyrobot/tree/c46a95c5cf4608257db171e0f716a15948d14ae2) (Please refer to see the whole project)

**cli.rb**

```
module Robot
  class CLI

    def initialize
      options = {:file => nil , :x => 5 , :y => 5}
      parser = OptionParser.new do|opts|
        opts.banner = "Usage: toyrobot [options]"

        opts.on('-f', '--file filepath', 'Filepath for input commands') do |filename|
          options[:file] = filename
        end

        opts.on('-x', '--xcoordinate X', 'Max X co-ordinate(Number)') do |max_x|
          begin
            options[:x] =  Integer(max_x)
          rescue
            puts "Invalid x argument"
            puts opts
            exit
          end  
        end

        opts.on('-y', '--ycoordinate Y', 'Max Y co-ordinate(Number)') do |max_y|
          begin
           options[:y] =  Integer(max_y)
          rescue
            puts "Invalid y argument"
            puts opts
            exit
          end 
        end

        opts.on('-h', '--help', 'Displays Help') do
          puts opts
          exit
        end
     end   
     parser.parse!
      @application = Robot::App.new(options)
    end

    def start
      @application.start
    end

  end
end
```

**app.rb**

```
module Robot
 class App
   def initialize(opts)
     @input_file = opts[:file].nil? ?  STDIN : File.open(opts[:file]) 
     @simulator  = Robot::Simulator.new opts[:x], opts[:y]
   end

   def start     
     command = read_command
     while (command) do  
       $logger.debug("Received command #{command}")
       begin
        @simulator.execute command
       rescue => e
         $logger.error(e)
       end
       command = read_command
     end
   end

   def read_command
     print "# " if @input_file == STDIN
     command = @input_file.gets
     exit if command.nil? || (command.chomp.downcase == ".quit")
     command  
   end

 end
end
```

**command_parser.rb**

```
module Robot
  class CommandParser

    @@number_reg = /^\d+$/

    # allowed_commnads is a hash 
    # with value as :method => [[arg types],[regex_range_for_strings_only]]
    def initialize(allowed_commands)
      @allowed_commands = allowed_commands
      $logger.info("Allowed commands are #{@allowed_commands.keys}")
    end

    def parse command
        $logger.debug("Parsing command #{command}")       
        args = command.split " "
        method = args.delete_at(0)

        if valid?(method, args)   
          update_args! method , args
          yield method , args
          return true
        else
          $logger.warn("Parsing failed. Invalid #{command}")
          return false
        end
    end


   private

     def update_args! method , args     
       @allowed_commands[method][0].each_with_index do |arg_type,i|
         case arg_type
           when :number
             args[i] = args[i].to_i 
           when :string
         end
       end
     end


     def valid? (method , args) 
       return false unless @allowed_commands.has_key? method

       unless  @allowed_commands[method].nil?
         return false unless @allowed_commands[method][0].size == args.size
         @allowed_commands[method][0].each_with_index do |arg_type,i|
           case arg_type
             when :number
               return false unless args[i] =~ @@number_reg
             when :string
               allowed_reg = @allowed_commands[method][1][i]
               unless allowed_reg.nil?
                 return false unless args[i] =~ /#{allowed_reg}/
               end
            end    
          end
        end
        return true
      end

  end
end
```

**direction.rb**

```
module Robot

    class Direction

     attr_accessor :direction

   def initialize(direction)
     @direction = direction
   end

   @NORTH = Direction.new "NORTH"
   @SOUTH = Direction.new "SOUTH"
   @EAST  = Direction.new "EAST"
   @WEST  = Direction.new "WEST"

   @CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS = [@NORTH,@EAST,@SOUTH,@WEST]

   def to_s
      @direction
   end

   class << self
     attr_accessor :NORTH, :SOUTH, :EAST, :WEST  
   end

   def self.find(direction)
     @CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS.find{|d| d.direction == direction.upcase }
   end

   def self.left(direction)
      @CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS[( @CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS.index(direction) - 1 ) % 4]  
   end

    def self.right(direction)
      @CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS[( @CLOCKWISE_DIRECTIONS.index(direction) + 1 ) % 4]  
   end

 end

end
```

**position.rb**

```
module Robot
  class Position

    attr_accessor :x, :y, :direction

    def initialize(x,y,direction)
      @x = x
      @y = y
      @direction = direction
    end

    def to_s
      "X= #{@x} Y=#{@y} Facing=#{@direction.to_s}"
    end

     def equal?(another_position)
      self.x == another_position.x &&
      self.y == another_position.y &&
      self.direction == another_position.direction
     end

    def move      
       curr_postion   = self.dup
       case curr_postion.direction
         when Direction.NORTH
           curr_postion.y +=1   
         when Direction.SOUTH
           curr_postion.y -=1 
         when Direction.EAST
           curr_postion.x +=1 
         when Direction.WEST
           curr_postion.x -=1   
       end
       curr_postion
    end

    def left
      curr_postion   = self.dup
      curr_postion.direction = Direction.left @direction
      curr_postion
    end

    def right
      curr_postion   = self.dup
      curr_postion.direction = Direction.right @direction
      curr_postion
    end

  end
end
```

**simulator.rb**

```
module Robot

  class Simulator

     attr_accessor :toy_robot

     def initialize max_x, max_y
       commands = {
                   "PLACE"  => [
                                 [:number , :number , :string],
                                 [nil,nil,"^NORTH$|^SOUTH$|^EAST$|^WEST$"]
                               ], 
                   "MOVE"   => [[],[]], 
                   "LEFT"   => [[],[]],
                   "RIGHT"  => [[],[]], 
                   "REPORT" => [[],[]] 
                  }
       @command_parser = CommandParser.new(commands)
       @table          = Table.new max_x , max_y
       @toy_robot      = ToyRobot.new
       $logger.info "Simulator created successfully."
     end

     def execute(command)
        r = @command_parser.parse(command) do |method,args|
          $logger.debug("#{method.downcase} - args #{args}")
          self.send( method.downcase , * args)
        end
        $logger.debug(@toy_robot.to_s)
     end

     def place x , y , face
       if @table.inside?(x, y)
         @toy_robot.position = Position.new(x, y, Direction.find(face))
         @toy_robot.placed   = true
       end
     end

     def move
       return unless @toy_robot.placed     
       next_position =  @toy_robot.position.move
       if @table.inside? next_position.x , next_position.y
         @toy_robot.position = next_position
       else
         ignore
       end
     end

     def left
       return unless @toy_robot.placed  
       @toy_robot.position = @toy_robot.position.left  
     end

     def right
       return unless @toy_robot.placed
       @toy_robot.position = @toy_robot.position.right
     end

     def report
       if @toy_robot.placed
         puts "#{@toy_robot.position.x} #{@toy_robot.position.y} #{@toy_robot.position.direction}"
       else
         puts "Robot is not placed yet. Please use PLACE command to place the robot."
       end
     end

     def ignore
       $logger.debug "Ignored step towards #{toy_robot.position.direction}"
     end

  end
end
```

**table.rb**

```
module Robot
  class Table

     def initialize max_x , max_y
        @MAX_X = max_x
        @MAX_Y = max_y
        $logger.info "Table boundaries are #{@MAX_X},#{@MAX_Y}"
     end

     def inside? x,y
       return ((0..@MAX_X-1) === x) && ((0..@MAX_Y-1) === y) 
     end

  end
end
```

**toyrobot.rb**

```
module Robot
  class ToyRobot
    attr_accessor :position, :placed

    def initialize
      @position  = nil
      @placed    = false
      $logger.info "Toy Robot created successfully."
    end

    def to_s
      if @placed 
       "Placed at #{@position.to_s}"
      else  
      "Not placed"
      end
    end

  end
end
```

**robot.rb**

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require "optparse"
require "logger" 
require "robot/version"
require 'robot/command_parser'
require 'robot/table'
require 'robot/position'
require 'robot/toy_robot'
require "robot/direction"
require "robot/simulator"
require "robot/app"
require "robot/cli"

$logger = Logger.new('log/toy_robot.log')
```

**Test code**

**command_parser_spec.rb**

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'
require_relative '../../lib/robot'

include Robot

describe CommandParser do

  subject(:command_parser) {CommandParser.new({
                   "Salute" => [
                                 [:string],
                                 ["^Hello$|^Namaste$"]
                                ],

                    "Name" => [
                                 [:string],
                                 []
                              ] ,
                    "Age" => [
                                 [:number],
                                 []
                              ]                      

              })}


  context "#with valid command" do  

    context "with range" do
      before {
                @ran    = false
                @called = command_parser.parse "Salute Hello" do |m,a|
                  @ran = true
                  @m = m
                  @a = a
                end
      }

      it { expect(@ran).to    be true }
      it { expect(@called).to be true }  
      it { expect(@a.size).to be 1    } 
      it { expect(@a[0]).to  match "Hello"  } 
      it { expect(@m).to     match "Salute" }      
    end


  context "without range" do   

     context "with string" do  
       before {
                @ran    = false
                @called = command_parser.parse "Name Tom" do |m,a|
                  @ran = true
                  @m = m
                  @a = a
                end
               }

       it { expect(@ran).to be true    }
       it { expect(@called).to be true }
       it { expect(@a.size).to be 1    } 
       it { expect(@a[0]).to  match "Tom"  } 
       it { expect(@m).to     match "Name" }    
     end

     context "with number" do
       before {
                @ran = false
                @called = command_parser.parse "Age 50" do |m,a|
                          @ran    = true
                          @m      = m
                          @a      = a
                end
       }

       it { expect(@ran).to    be true }
       it { expect(@called).to be true }
       it { expect(@a.size).to be 1    }   
       it { expect(@a[0]).to   be 50   } 
       it { expect(@m).to     match      "Age"}  
       end
    end    
  end      



  context "#with invalid command" do    
    before {
                @ran = false
                @called = command_parser.parse "Salute Hi" do |m,a|
                  @ran = true
                end 
     }

     it { expect(@called).to be false }
     it { expect(@called).to be false }        
    end

end
```

**direction_spec.rb**

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'
require_relative '../../lib/robot'
include Robot

describe Direction do

  describe ":: finds directions" do
     it { expect( Direction.find "NORTH" ).to be Direction.NORTH }
     it { expect( Direction.find "SOUTH" ).to be Direction.SOUTH }
     it { expect( Direction.find "EAST"  ).to be Direction.EAST  }
     it { expect( Direction.find "WEST"  ).to be Direction.WEST  }
  end

  describe ":: turns left" do
     it { expect( Direction.left Direction.NORTH ).to be Direction.WEST }
     it { expect( Direction.left Direction.SOUTH ).to be Direction.EAST }
     it { expect( Direction.left Direction.EAST ).to be Direction.NORTH }
     it { expect( Direction.left Direction.WEST ).to be Direction.SOUTH }
  end

  describe ":: turns right" do
     it { expect( Direction.right Direction.NORTH ).to be Direction.EAST }
     it { expect( Direction.right Direction.SOUTH ).to be Direction.WEST }
     it { expect( Direction.right Direction.EAST ).to be Direction.SOUTH }
     it { expect( Direction.right Direction.WEST ).to be Direction.NORTH }
  end

end
```

**position_spec.rb**

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'
require_relative '../../lib/robot'
include Robot

describe Position do

  context "#moves correctly to north" do
    before {
      @position      = Position.new(2, 3, Direction.NORTH)
      @curr_position = @position.move
    }

    it { expect(@curr_position.x).to be 2 }
    it { expect(@curr_position.y).to be 4 }
    it { expect(@curr_position.direction).to be Direction.NORTH }

  end

  context "#moves correctly to south" do
    before {
      @position      = Position.new(2, 3, Direction.SOUTH)
      @curr_position = @position.move
    }

    it { expect(@curr_position.x).to be 2 }
    it { expect(@curr_position.y).to be 2 }
    it { expect(@curr_position.direction).to be Direction.SOUTH }

  end

  context "#moves correctly to east" do
    before {
      @position      = Position.new(2, 3, Direction.EAST)
      @curr_position = @position.move
    }

    it { expect(@curr_position.x).to be 3 }
    it { expect(@curr_position.y).to be 3 }
    it { expect(@curr_position.direction).to be Direction.EAST }

  end

  context "#moves correctly to west" do
    before {
      @position      = Position.new(2, 3, Direction.WEST)
      @curr_position = @position.move
    }

    it { expect(@curr_position.x).to be 1 }
    it { expect(@curr_position.y).to be 3 }
    it { expect(@curr_position.direction).to be Direction.WEST }

  end

  context "#turns left" do
    before {
      start_position  = Position.new(2, 3, Direction.WEST)
      @position  = start_position.left
    }

    it { expect(@position.x).to be 2 }
    it { expect(@position.y).to be 3 }
    it { expect(@position.direction).to be Direction.SOUTH }
  end

  context "#turns right" do
    before {
      start_position  = Position.new(2, 3, Direction.WEST)
      @position       = start_position.right
    }

    it { expect(@position.x).to be 2 }
    it { expect(@position.y).to be 3 }
    it { expect(@position.direction).to be Direction.NORTH }
  end

end
```

**simualtor_spec.rb**

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'
require_relative '../../lib/robot'
include Robot

describe Simulator do

  describe "#gets placed" do
    before {
      @simulator = Simulator.new 5,5
      @simulator.place 2, 3, "NORTH"
    }

    it { expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(2,3,Direction.NORTH) }

  end

  describe "#moves" do

    context "when inside table" do
      before {
        @simulator = Simulator.new 5,5
        @simulator.place 2, 3, "NORTH"
        @simulator.move
      }
      it { expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(2,4,Direction.NORTH) }
    end

    context "when at edge of table" do
      before {
        @simulator = Simulator.new 5,5
        @simulator.place 4, 4, "NORTH"
        @simulator.move
      }
      it { expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(4,4,Direction.NORTH) }
    end

  end

  describe "# turns" do

    context "when faced north" do
      before {
          @simulator = Simulator.new 5,5
          @simulator.place 2, 2, "NORTH"       
      }

      it { @simulator.left  ; expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(2,2,Direction.WEST) }
      it { @simulator.right ; expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(2,2,Direction.EAST) }
     end

     context "when faced south" do
      before {
          @simulator = Simulator.new 5,5
          @simulator.place 2, 2, "SOUTH"       
      }

      it { @simulator.left  ; expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(2,2,Direction.EAST) }
      it { @simulator.right ; expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(2,2,Direction.WEST) }
     end 

     context "when faced east" do
      before {
          @simulator = Simulator.new 5,5
          @simulator.place 2, 2, "EAST"       
      }

      it { @simulator.left  ; expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(2,2,Direction.NORTH) }
      it { @simulator.right ; expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(2,2,Direction.SOUTH) }
     end  

     context "when faced west" do
      before {
          @simulator = Simulator.new 5,5
          @simulator.place 2, 2, "WEST"       
      }

      it { @simulator.left  ; expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(2,2,Direction.SOUTH) }
      it { @simulator.right ; expect(@simulator.toy_robot.position).to be Position.new(2,2,Direction.NORTH) }
     end  

  end

end
```

**table_spec.rb**

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'
require_relative '../../lib/robot'
include Robot

describe Table do

  context "#checks boundry" do
    before { @t = Table.new 5,5 }
    it {expect(@t.inside?(2,3)).to be true}
    it {expect(@t.inside?(0,0)).to be true}
    it {expect(@t.inside?(5,5)).to be false}
    it {expect(@t.inside?(5,3)).to be false}
    it {expect(@t.inside?(3,5)).to be false}
    it {expect(@t.inside?(6,3)).to be false}
    it {expect(@t.inside?(3,6)).to be false}
    it {expect(@t.inside?(-1,0)).to be false}
    it {expect(@t.inside?(0,-1)).to be false}
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Initial impressions

There's a lot of code.  Interviewers don't like to read a lot of code.

In many ways, you have overdelivered on the specification.  Since you have indicated that this was an [interview-question](/questions/tagged/interview-question), I'm going to give you my personal value judgements on these points.

- I'm ambivalent about the logger.  On one hand, it is a nice debugging aid.  On the other hand, the spec just says that any invalid instruction is to be ignored, so all of those infos, warnings, and errors are unnecessary complications.  The spec certainly did not ask for a `log/toy_robot.log` file to be created by default, so that was a bit of a surprise.

  Do you really need to log `"Toy Robot created successfully"` and `"Simulator created successfully"` at the "info" level?  I'd consider those to be "debug"-level messages, and even then, I'd wonder what could possibly go wrong in such a simple program that the `ToyRobot` and `Simulator` would fail to be instantiated.

  Instead of logging warnings and errors, you could have just thrown exceptions, catching and reporting them in one exception handler.
- The very first requirement states that the table is a 5 × 5 square.  Why are you bothering to accept `-x` and `-y` flags to specify the width and height?  You could have ditched the entire `cli.rb` file, accepting no command-line options, and just read from `ARGF` to satisfy the requirement that the input can come from a file or from standard input.

I'm not convinced that all of those classes need to exist.

- As I mentioned, `OptionParser` isn't called for, so the `CLI` class can go away.
- Why is `App` a separate class from `CLI`?  What about `Simulator`?  Isn't this whole project a simulator app?
- The `ToyRobot` class looks more like a "dumb" struct rather than a "smart" object.
- The code to support rotations and translations is split up between `Direction` and `Position`.
- What is `Position#equal?` used for?  What about `Position#to_s` — couldn't you have defined it strategically so that it can be reused for the `REPORT` command?

So, there is some overengineering going on, and some bloat, acting together to produce a solution that is larger than it needs to be.

### Second impressions

You do seem familiar with Ruby.  For example, you used ranges and `===` to perform the bounds check instead of `0 <= x && x < @MAX_X && 0 <= y && y < @MAX_Y`.

> ```
>  def inside? x,y
>    return ((0..@MAX_X-1) === x) && ((0..@MAX_Y-1) === y) 
>  end
> ```

On the other hand, it would have been slightly prettier with exclusive ranges, and without the explicit `return`:

```
 def inside?(x, y)
   (0...@MAX_X) === x && (0...@MAX_Y) === y
 end
```

The `Direction` enum class is not bad — it demonstrates familiarity with metaprogramming.  The `attr_accessor`s would be better as `attr_reader`s, since they should all be constant.

### Command dispatching

This is the main point of the exercise.

You've split up the work between `App`, `CommandParser` and `Simulator`.  Within the `Simulator` constructor, there is a `command` hash that is mostly there to support the `PLACE` command parameters, and you're repeating yourself by having to list those commands explicitly.

In `App#read_command`, instead of calling `exit`, I suggest a more disciplined throw-catch.

### Suggested solution

For comparison, this is what I came up with.

```
class Direction
  def initialize(sym, dx, dy, left, right)
    @name, @dx, @dy, @left, @right = sym.to_s, dx, dy, left, right
  end

  def to_s
    @name
  end

  def left
    Direction.const_get(@left)
  end

  def right
    Direction.const_get(@right)
  end

  def advance(x, y)
    [x + @dx, y + @dy]
  end

  @all = [
    [:EAST,  +1,  0],
    [:NORTH,  0, +1],
    [:WEST,  -1,  0],
    [:SOUTH,  0, -1],
  ]
  @all.each_with_index do |(sym, dx, dy), i|
    self.const_set(sym,
                   Direction.new(sym, dx, dy, @all[(i + 1) % @all.size].first,
                                              @all[(i - 1) % @all.size].first))
  end

  def self.[](name)
    Direction.const_get(name) if Direction.const_defined?(name)
  end
end
```

```
class InvalidCommand < Exception ; end
```

```
# Mixin for Robot
module Commands
  def place(x, y, face)
    validate(x = (x.to_i if /\A\d+\Z/.match(x)),
             y = (y.to_i if /\A\d+\Z/.match(y)),
             face = Direction[face.upcase])
    @x, @y, @face = x, y, face
  end

  def move
    raise InvalidCommand.new unless @face
    new_x, new_y = @face.advance(@x, @y)
    validate(new_x, new_y, @face)
    @x, @y = new_x, new_y
  end

  def left
    raise InvalidCommand.new unless @face
    @face = @face.left
  end

  def right
    raise InvalidCommand.new unless @face
    @face = @face.right
  end

  def report
    raise InvalidCommand.new unless @face
    @output.puts "#{@x},#{@y},#{@face}"
  end
end
```

```
class Robot
  include Commands

  def initialize(board_size=5, output=STDOUT)
    @board_size = board_size
    @output = output
  end

  def execute(cmd)
    cmd = cmd.strip.downcase
    op, args = cmd.split(/\s+/, 2)
    args = args.split(/\s*,\s*/) if args
    raise InvalidCommand.new unless Commands.public_method_defined?(op)
    begin
      send(op, *args)
    rescue ArgumentError
      raise InvalidCommand.new
    end
  end

  def execute_script(io)
    io.each_line do |line|
      begin
        execute(line)
      rescue InvalidCommand
        #puts "(Ignored invalid command)"
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def validate(x, y, f)
    raise InvalidCommand.new unless x && y && f
    raise InvalidCommand.new unless (0..@board_size) === x
    raise InvalidCommand.new unless (0..@board_size) === y
  end
end
```

```
Robot.new.execute_script(ARGF)
```